# How can I use Hot-Start feature of MOSEK

Tags: performance, initialization, mosek

I have a simple linear programming problem. After solving it, I get the correct result. I want to speed it up using hot-start feature of MOSEK, but I don't know how to set some parameters like "res.sol.bas.sku", "res.sol.bas.skn", .... I only know an initial solution, i.e, "res.sol.bas.xx", where the value of the variables are stored for a near to optimal solution. Is it possible for me to accelerate the engine using Hot start feature in this way!

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You seem to using MATLAB. Did you read

http://docs.mosek.com/6.0/toolbox/node009.html#238393032

Does it solve the issue?